# Capture console output with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

i have this remote web page :

test.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log(5 + 6);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to create a script in node.js that can return "11"

I tried to use phantom.js. But, I don't get any result.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create()
.then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage()
    .then(function(page) {
        page.open('http://localhost:8888/test.html')
        .then(function(status) {
            console.log(status);
            page.property('onConsoleMessage')
            .then(function(content) {
                console.log(content);
                page.close();
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```